# How to configure loader for specific file types (xml) in vite

Tags: javascript, vite

I am using vite 5.1, and have got xml files required in JavaScript like `require('file.xml')`

But when I am running dev, I am getting the error:

```
ERROR No loader is configured for ".xml" files
```

My vite configuration looks like:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.xml']
})
```

I cannot modify the require like `require('file.xml?raw')` since that line of code comes from a dependency which I don't own.